# Getting an ITIN or SSN | USA

Tags: united-states, irs, itin, ssn

I am asking this on behalf of a friend. This question is relevant for USA.

==== Her question is following ====

I recently came to the USA and am on F2 visa (student category). I am not working professionally in the US and am not getting paid from any source. I want to get an ITIN (or SSN) issued before the financial year ends. What is the process for that? I tried calling IRS multiple times, but was never able to speak to an agent. Also, I didn't find the application process on the website.

Also, do I need to apply from state of my residence only? Or can I apply it from any other state too? I am asking this because I am planning to visit friends in different states during the holiday period.

==== Ends ====

Please feel free to ask follow up questions or clarification.

Answer (score 3):

F2 is the dependent (spouse or child) of an F1 student. Someone on F2 is not authorized to work in the US, so would not be eligible for an SSN. If you file a US tax return (e.g. if you have income or your spouse has income and you guys file jointly), you can get an ITIN, but you can only apply for the ITIN together with your tax return filing. You would only file a 2021 tax return in early 2022. Unless you have a past year tax return that you need to file, you would not be able to get an ITIN now. The state doesn't matter.

Comment: Perfectly said.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can she do this while filing her husband's tax via TurboTax?

Comment: @PHcoDer: Only if they file jointly. And they can only file jointly if one of them is a "resident alien" for tax purposes (i.e. passes the Substantial Presence Test or Green Card Test) for the year. Due to some complicated rules, people in F1 or F2 status generally won't pass the Substantial Presence Test for the first 5 calendar years they are here. I don't think TurboTax can file nonresident alien tax returns.

Comment: @user102008. Thank you. They are resident alien. However, see the turbotax response to this same question at the link below. According to that response an ITIN is needed for the returns. So it means one needs to get ITIN before filing. Right? Can you please clarify?
https://ttlc.intuit.com/community/taxes/discussion/re-getting-an-itin-or-ssn-usa/01/2384296/highlight/true#M851093

Comment: @PHcoDer: No. One cannot get ITIN before filing. They would submit both the ITIN application (W-7) and the tax return together. If they use TurboTax, they would have to leave the SSN/ITIN field blank, print it out instead of submitting it online, and submit the paper tax return together with the W-7.